# Why is my csh script not working with special characters?

Tags: shell, csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f

foreach line ("`cat test`")
    set x=`echo "$line" | awk '{split($0, b, " "); print b[1]}'`
    echo "$x"
end
```

test file contains following contents:

```
How to Format
Stack[7] Overflow
Put returns between paragraphs
```

On executing the script I am getting following error:

```
set: No match.
```

How to store the string which contains special character like square brackets `[]` in a variable and then use them in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing:

```
set x = [some string with shell globbing characters]
```

This won't work for the same reason that `set x = foo` works, but `set x = [foo]` doesn't. You need to use `set x = "[foo]"` (or `'[foo]'`) to escape the special shell globbing characters (`[` and `]` in this case).

Nesting quotes in the C shell is pretty hard, and it's one the reasons [it's generally discouraged to use the C shell for scripting](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). It's perhaps possible for your command, but I'm not smart enough (or too lazy) to figure out how. My solution is typically to set the special `noglob` variable to prevent expansion of globbing characters:

```
set noglob
foreach line ("`cat test`")
    set x = `echo "$line" | awk '{split($0, b, " "); print b[1]}'`
    echo "$x"
end
```

outputs:

```
How
Stack[7]
Put
```

---

P.S. There is an easier way to echo the first word of every line; put it in a list:

```
set noglob
foreach line ("`cat test`")
    set x = ($line)
    echo "$x[1]"
end
```